# Transition density of Brownian motion in half space

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $H=\{x\in \mathcal R^d:x_d\geq0\}$ is the half space of $d$-dimensional Euclidean space, it is said that there is a explicit transition density formula for killed Brownian motion in $H$, but i can't find the formula. Any help please. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

One result that might help is mentioned in *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion* by Revuz & Yor. They note (e.g. page 87, 494) that
$$
   p_t(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\left[ 
   \exp\left( \frac{-1}{2t}(y-x)^2 \right) 
   -
   \exp\left( \frac{-1}{2t}(y+x)^2 \right)
   \right]
$$
for $x,y>0$ is the transition density of Brownian motion killed when it reaches 0.